# QSettings subclass does not have any keys

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on project as addition to existing Java app. This Java app has its configuration file, like this:

```
screen.600800=false
payment.commerceid=
machine.printer=printer\:(Default),receipt
paper.standard.mediasizename=A4
machine.printername=(Show dialog)
payments.textoverlay=false
paper.receipt.height=546
till.receiptsize=1
swing.defaultlaf=org.pushingpixels.substance.skinpack.StreetlightsSkin
paper.standard.y=72
paper.standard.x=72
table.tablecolour=black
till.SCRate=0
format.integer=\#,\#\#0
user.language=sl
paper.receipt.width=190
till.receiptprintoff=false
db.user=user
start.text=
machine.uniqueinstance=false
menu.autohide=false
till.pricewith00=false
table.waitercolour=red
format.double=\#,\#\#0.\#
user.country=
till.amountattop=false
till.pickupsize=1
till.autoLogoffrestaurant=false
machine.screenmode=window
screen.receipt.columns=42
machine.printer.6=Not defined
machine.printer.5=Not defined
db.engine=MySQL
machine.printer.4=Not defined
user.variant=
machine.printer.3=screen
machine.printer.2=printer\:(Show dialog),standard
payment.gateway=Not defined
till.SCOnOff=false
start.logo=logo.png
format.percent=\#,\#\#0.\#\#%
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
table.showwaiterdetails=true
format.date=
machine.ticketsbag=simple
db.driverlib=/opt/uBlagajna/./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
table.showcustomerdetails=true
db.password=test
till.receiptprefix=
paper.standard.height=698
table.customercolour=blue
till.taxincluded=false
paper.standard.width=451
till.autotimer=100
machine.display=screen
payment.testmode=true
format.datetime=
machine.scanner=Not defined
machine.hostname=work002
till.autoLogoff=false
paper.receipt.y=10
paper.receipt.x=10
payment.magcardreader=Not defined
payment.commercepassword=password
format.time=
format.currency='EUR' \#,\#\#0.00
db.URL=jdbc\:mysql\://127.0.0.1\:3306/testdb
till.hideinfo=false
machine.scale=Not defined
paper.receipt.mediasizename=A4
till.SCRestaurant=false
till.marineoption=false
```

Now, whatever I do on Qt C++ side, I cannot get values from keys. Therefore I've subclassed QSettings class as in here:

```
#ifndef UEPOSSESTTINGS_H
#define UEPOSSESTTINGS_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

#include "settings/uedefaults.h"

class UePOSSesttings : public QSettings
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QString m_strSettingsFilePath;
    QString m_strParsedData;
    QString m_strDbUrl;

    inline void ueSetConfigurationFilePath(const QString& path)
        { this->m_strSettingsFilePath=path; }

    inline QString ueParsedData() const
        { return this->m_strParsedData; }
    inline void ueSetParsedData(const QString& data)
        { this->m_strParsedData=data; }

    inline QString ueDbUrl() const
        { return this->m_strDbUrl; }
    inline void ueSetDbUrl(const QString& dbUrl)
        { this->m_strDbUrl=dbUrl; }

    void ueParseData(const QString& filename);

public:
    UePOSSesttings(const QString& organization,
                   const QString & application=QString(),
                   QObject* parent = 0);
    UePOSSesttings(const QString& fileName,
                   Format format,
                   QObject* parent = 0);
    ~UePOSSesttings();

    static QString ueSearchConfigurationFile();

    inline QString ueConfigurationFilePath() const
        { return this->m_strSettingsFilePath; }

    QString ueReadDbDriver() const;
    QString ueReadDbPassword() const;
    QString ueReadDbUrl() const;
    QString ueReadDbDriverLib() const;
    QString ueReadDbEngine() const;
    QString ueReadDbUser() const;
    QString ueReadDbHostname() const;
    QString ueReadDbName() const;
    int ueReadDbPort() const;
};


    #endif // UEPOSSESTTINGS_H
```

and implementation:

```
#include "uepossesttings.h"

UePOSSesttings::UePOSSesttings(const QString& organization,
                               const QString& application,
                               QObject* parent)
    : QSettings(organization,
                application,
                parent)
{
    this->setDefaultFormat(QSettings::NativeFormat);

    this->ueSetConfigurationFilePath(UePOSSesttings::ueSearchConfigurationFile());
    this->ueParseData(this->ueConfigurationFilePath());
}

UePOSSesttings::UePOSSesttings(const QString& fileName,
               Format format,
               QObject* parent)
    : QSettings(fileName,
                format,
                parent)
{
    this->ueSetConfigurationFilePath(fileName);
    this->ueParseData(this->ueConfigurationFilePath());
}

UePOSSesttings::~UePOSSesttings()
{
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueSearchConfigurationFile()
{
    QDirIterator dirIterator("/home",
                             QStringList() << UeDefaults::UeApplication::APPLICATION_SETTINGS_FILE,
                             QDir::Files,
                             QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    while(dirIterator.hasNext())
    {
        dirIterator.next();

        if(dirIterator.fileName()==UeDefaults::UeApplication::APPLICATION_SETTINGS_FILE)
        {
            return dirIterator.filePath();
        }   // if
    }   // while

    return dirIterator.filePath();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbDriver() const
{
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_DRIVER).toString();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbPassword() const
{
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_PASSWORD).toString();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbUrl() const
{
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_URL).toString();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbDriverLib() const
{
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_DRIVER_LIB).toString();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbEngine() const
{
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_ENGINE).toString();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbUser() const
{
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_USER).toString();
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbHostname() const
{
    int iDbHostnameIndexStart=this->ueDbUrl().indexOf("//")+2;
    int iDbHostnameIndexStop=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf(":");

    QString strHostname=this->ueDbUrl().mid(iDbHostnameIndexStart,
                                            (iDbHostnameIndexStop-iDbHostnameIndexStart));

    return strHostname;
}

QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbName() const
{
    int iDbNameIndexStart=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf("/")+1;
    int iDbNameIndexStop=this->ueDbUrl().size();

    QString strDbName=this->ueDbUrl().mid(iDbNameIndexStart,
                                          (iDbNameIndexStop-iDbNameIndexStart));

    return strDbName;
}

int UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbPort() const
{
    int iDbPortIndexStart=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf(":")+1;
    int iDbPortIndexStop=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf("/");

    QString strPort=this->ueDbUrl().mid(iDbPortIndexStart,
                                        (iDbPortIndexStop-iDbPortIndexStart));

    return strPort.toInt();
}

void UePOSSesttings::ueParseData(const QString& filename)
{
    QFile settingsFile(filename);
    QString data;

    settingsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    data=QString::fromLatin1(settingsFile.readAll().constData());
    data.replace("\\:",
                 ":");
    this->ueSetParsedData(data);

    int iDbUrlIndexStart=data.indexOf(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_URL);
    int iDbUrlIndexStop=data.indexOf("\n",
                                     iDbUrlIndexStart);
    QString strDbUrl=data.mid(iDbUrlIndexStart,
                              (iDbUrlIndexStop-iDbUrlIndexStart));
    this->ueSetDbUrl(strDbUrl);

    settingsFile.close();
}
```

Now, whatever I do, I the that short method via `ueRead`...., for instance, `ueReadUser()` returns empty string. Does anyone has some idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not, how you derive `QSettings`. [This is how you derive QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#registerFormat).

Comment: @Amartel do you have maybe some example, because I have no idea how to implement `readFunc` and `writeFunc`

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but this is [my implementation of XmlSettings](https://yadi.sk/d/8aEmohpzi7QyZ).

Comment: @Amartel what if I dispose `QSettings` and derive from `QObject` and then with string manipulation tecniques get data that I need?

Comment: You can write your own settings class without using `QSettings`, of cource. You don't even need to derive `QObject` for this. Depends on what you actually need. `QSettings` is usefull in two cases: 1. you understand how it works and find it easier to use it then to write your own class from scratch. 2. You need to provide identical interface for several data sources, like xml, ini etc. If neither is your case, then... go ahead.

Comment: @Amartel thank you for guidelines! Will report code result as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dumped the QSettings and here is working code. Header:

```
#ifndef UEPOSSETTINGS_H
#define UEPOSSETTINGS_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

#include "uedefaults.h"

class UePOSSettings : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QString m_strSettingsFilePath;
    QString m_strParsedData;
    QString m_strDbUrl;
    QString m_strUser;
    QString m_strPassword;
    QString m_strHostname;
    QString m_strDbName;
    int m_iDbPort;

    inline void ueSetConfigurationFilePath(const QString& path)
        { this->m_strSettingsFilePath=path; }
    inline QString ueParsedData() const
        { return this->m_strParsedData; }
    inline void ueSetParsedData(const QString& data)
        { this->m_strParsedData=data; }

    inline QString ueDbUrl() const
        { return this->m_strDbUrl; }
    inline void ueSetDbUrl(const QString& dbUrl)
        { this->m_strDbUrl=dbUrl; }
    inline void ueSetDbUser(const QString& dbUser)
        { this->m_strUser=dbUser; }
    inline void ueSetDbPassword(const QString& dbPassword)
        { this->m_strPassword=dbPassword; }
    inline void ueSetDbHostname(const QString& dbHostname)
        { this->m_strHostname=dbHostname; }
    inline void ueSetDbName(const QString& dbName)
        { this->m_strDbName=dbName; }
    inline void ueSetDbPort(const int& dbPort)
        { this->m_iDbPort=dbPort; }

    void ueParseData(const QString& filename);

public:
    explicit UePOSSettings(QObject *parent = 0);

    ~UePOSSettings();

    Q_INVOKABLE static QString ueSearchConfigurationFile();

    inline QString ueConfigurationFilePath() const
        { return this->m_strSettingsFilePath; }

    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDbUser() const
        { return this->m_strUser; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDbPassword() const
        { return this->m_strPassword; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDbHostname() const
        { return this->m_strHostname; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDbName() const
        { return this->m_strDbName; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline int ueDbPort() const
        { return this->m_iDbPort; }
};

#endif // UEPOSSETTINGS_H
```

Implementation:

```
#include "uepossettings.h"

UePOSSettings::UePOSSettings(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    this->ueSetConfigurationFilePath(UePOSSettings::ueSearchConfigurationFile());
    this->ueParseData(this->ueConfigurationFilePath());
}   // default constructor

UePOSSettings::~UePOSSettings()
{
}   // destructor

QString UePOSSettings::ueSearchConfigurationFile()
{
    QDirIterator dirIterator("/home",
                             QStringList() << UeDefaults::UeApplication::APPLICATION_SETTINGS_FILE,
                             QDir::Files,
                             QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    while(dirIterator.hasNext())
    {
        dirIterator.next();

        if(dirIterator.fileName()==UeDefaults::UeApplication::APPLICATION_SETTINGS_FILE)
        {
            return dirIterator.filePath();
        }   // if
    }   // while

    return dirIterator.filePath();
}   // ueSearchConfigurationFile

void UePOSSettings::ueParseData(const QString& filename)
{
    QFile settingsFile(filename);
    QString data;

    settingsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    data=QString::fromLatin1(settingsFile.readAll().constData());
    data.replace("\\:",
                 ":");
    this->ueSetParsedData(data);

    int iDbUrlIndexStart=data.indexOf(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_URL);
    int iDbUrlIndexStop=data.indexOf("\n",
                                     iDbUrlIndexStart);
    QString strDbUrl=data.mid(iDbUrlIndexStart,
                             (iDbUrlIndexStop-iDbUrlIndexStart));
    this->ueSetDbUrl(strDbUrl);

    int iDbHostnameIndexStart=this->ueDbUrl().indexOf("//")+2;
    int iDbHostnameIndexStop=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf(":");
    this->ueSetDbHostname(this->ueDbUrl().mid(iDbHostnameIndexStart,
                                             (iDbHostnameIndexStop-iDbHostnameIndexStart)));

    int iDbNameIndexStart=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf("/")+1;
    int iDbNameIndexStop=this->ueDbUrl().size();

    this->ueSetDbName(this->ueDbUrl().mid(iDbNameIndexStart,
                                         (iDbNameIndexStop-iDbNameIndexStart)));

    int iDbPortIndexStart=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf(":")+1;
    int iDbPortIndexStop=this->ueDbUrl().lastIndexOf("/");

    QString strPort=this->ueDbUrl().mid(iDbPortIndexStart,
                                       (iDbPortIndexStop-iDbPortIndexStart));

    this->ueSetDbPort(strPort.toInt());

    int iDbUserIndexStart=data.indexOf(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_USER)+UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_USER.length()+1;
    int iDbUserIndexStop=data.indexOf("\n",
                                      iDbUserIndexStart);
    this->ueSetDbUser(data.mid(iDbUserIndexStart,
                              (iDbUserIndexStop-iDbUserIndexStart)));

    int iDbPasswordIndexStart=data.indexOf(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_PASSWORD)+UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_PASSWORD.length()+1;
    int iDbPasswordIndexStop=data.indexOf("\n",
                                          iDbPasswordIndexStart);
    QString test=data.mid(iDbPasswordIndexStart,
                          iDbPasswordIndexStop);
    this->ueSetDbPassword(data.mid(iDbPasswordIndexStart,
                                  (iDbPasswordIndexStop-iDbPasswordIndexStart)));

    settingsFile.close();
}   // ueParseData
```